# powershell script to attach the html file in body of email

Tags: html, powershell

Iam looking for a Powershell script to attach the html file in the body of email.Please help me by providing a sample script .My current script is not working .Iam not able to get the html file content in the body of email.Name of the html file changes every time.

Comment: "My current script is not working" - what current script? I don't see any code in the question

Comment: powershell -command "& {Send-MailMessage -from 'Sree.Hari@fo.com' -To 'Sree.Hari@fo.com'  -Subject 'Testing' -smtpServer smtp.fo.com -Body '$body= (Get-Content "D:\batch\.*html")'}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used 2 scripts but i suppose you could use one
Make the html file

```
            $FILENAME = HTMLfilename
            $head = @'
            <title>page title</title>
            <style> maybe some css</style>
            '@
            $title01 = @'
            <h1>some text above html file</h1>
            '@
            $body = @"
            <a href='$FILENAME.html'>filename</a> 
            '@
            $x = some code
            $x | Select-object Name | ConvertTo-HTML -head $head -PreContent $title01 -PostContent "some text" -body $body | Out-File "PATH\TO\HTML\FILE\$FILENAME.html"
```

Send the email

```
            $Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($EmailUsername, $Emailpassword)
            $EmailFrom = "from@domain.com" 
            $EmailTo = @("<to@domain.com>")
            #$EmailCc = @("<EMAIL>")
            $EmailSubject = "email  subject"
            $EmailBody = "a link to html file" 
            #OR maybe Attach it
            #$EmailAttachments = "PATH\TO\HTML\FILE\$FILENAME.html" 
            $SMTPServer = "smtp.@domain.com"
            $SMTPPort = ####
            $SMTPSsl = $True 
            $param = @{ 

            SmtpServer = $SMTPServer 
            Port = $SMTPPort 
            UseSsl = $SMTPSsl   
            Credential = $Credential    
            From = $EmailFrom   
            To = $EmailTo
            #Cc = $EmailCc  
            Subject = $EmailSubject 
            Body = $EmailBody 
            #Attachments = $EmailAttachments    
            } 


            Send-MailMessage @param
```

Comment: Hi Send-MailMessage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Port'.
At D:\BATCH\Validation.ps1:15 char:17
+ Send-MailMessage <<<<  @param
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage